# Стукать и стучать - в чем разница?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, словообразование, глаголы

Является ли глагол **"стукать"** устаревшим? Возможно ли его применение в настоящее время - будет ли это грамотно в разговорной речи? *И когда применять "стукать - стучать"?*

Answer (score 1):

Я бы написала "*стукнуть друг о дружку*", "*стукнуть по мячу палкой*", т.к. "ударять" и "бить" предполагают некоторую **неоднократность** действий, а надо раз! — и готово.

Comment: "Стукать" можно заменить на "бить", "ударять", а "стукнуть - на "ударить".

Answer (score 0):

Словарь Ефремовой 2000 г. помечает "стукать" как разговорное.

Стукать:
1. разг.; неперех. 
Ударять чем-либо, производя стук.

2. разг.; перех. 
   Бить, наносить побои.

Я бы сказал, слово "стукать" звучит странно в речи современного человека. Я бы не советовал применять его без особой надобности, лучше использовать нейтральное слово "стучать" - в смысле "ударять чем-либо, производя стук". А в смысле "бить, наносить побои" тоже можно подобрать нейтрально звучащие синонимы.

Answer (score 0):

**Стукнуть** ― ударить со стуком, глагол совершенного вида. **Стукать и стучать** ― глаголы несовершенного вида.  Для "стучать" основным значением является  **произвести стук**, глагол  "стукать"  ― это прежде всего **просто ударить**.

**Частотность употребления глагола "стукать" очень невелика** по сравнению со "стучать", но нельзя сказать, что мы можем обойтись без этого глагола, например:

Потом бросали в нее мячиком и даже пытались **стукать** по мячу палкой. Один раз  давали разноцветные яички, их надо было **стукать** друг об дружку.

Comment: "Нельзя сказать, что мы можем обойтись без этого глагола", - сильно сказано. А почему бы не заменить его в ваших примерах на "бить",  "ударять"?

Answer (score 0):

Если мы говорим "принялся стукать/стучать", глаголы являются синонимами.

Без вспомогательного вроде "принялся" у  слов разные значения: "он стукнул в дверь" (ясно, что это один удар), "он стучал в дверь" (ясно, что это несколько ударов).

В некоторых контекстах "стукать" будет синонимом "бить", а вот "стучать" подобное значение приобретёт только при помощи приставок, например: "настучать по голове", а вот "стукать по голове" звучит неуклюже.

Кроме того, у "стукать" имеется разговорный оттенок, хотя здесь тоже значительную роль, какими словами мы обрамляем глагол.

Таким образом, слова взаимозаменяемы, но не всегда, и различаются по ряду свойств.

Что касается поднятого в теме разговора о возможности обойтись без какого-либо слова, то очевидно, что мы способны обойтись в речи вообще без любого слова, либо заменив его на синоним, либо вообще избегая формулировок, где оно необходимо. Но это нецелесообразно: богатый словарь — один из главных инструментов литературы, интеллигент  будет в дверь стучать, а едва стоящий на ногах пьяница едва найдёт силы, чтобы разок стукнуть.

Comment: Стукать и стукнуть — разные глаголы, а в Вашем ответе они "слились" в один. Про *стукнуть* в вопросе ничего не было,

Comment: В словаре это один глагол.

Comment: Один глагол? Стукать - глагол несовершенного вида, Стукнуть ― глагол совершенного вида. Они отвечают на разные вопросы.

Comment: А причём тут вид глагола? Существительные в разных падежах Вы тоже назовёте разными существительными?

Comment: По-моему, Вы запутались. Самое простое: посмотрите еще раз в словари, вот вы пишете: "В словаре это один глагол", посмотрите еще раз, что пишет словарь. Второе, некорректно проводить аналогию между  видами глаголов и падежами существительных. Виды глаголов скорее можно сравнить со склонениями имен  существительных. А падежам аналога в мире глаголов нет.

Comment: У меня электронный словарь. В нём "стукать" и "стукнуть" находятся в одной статье. Я вполне могу ошибаться. Но всё же я бы поспорил с аналогией видов и склонений. Склонения подразумевают разные слова, а вид просто трансформирует слово, оставляя тот же корень. Как по мне, это близко именно к падежным изменениям. Впрочем, это другая история. Поиск в интернете подтверждает то, что словари  разделяют слова стукать и стукнуть в разные статьи.